# Refused to display '' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I've made an MVC ASP.NET C# project which is mainly a form.

However when I iframe the correct url, it shows up as blank

NOTE: i haven't done any line of code regarding iframe

Is there an option i need to turn on to make it possible to iframe?

```
FirefoxConsole Error message:

Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://localhost:2053/Persons/Create does not permit cross-origin framing.

 Chrome Error message: 

  Refused to display 'http://localhost:2053/Persons/Create' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

Comment: 'iframe the correct url' - can you explain this please?

Comment: <iframe src="http://localhost:2053/Persons/Create">

Also an online version doesnt work

Comment: can you browse to that url normally? (ie not in an iframe), and can you post the <head> code from the iframe page?

Comment: Sorry i messed something up, fixed my queston now

Comment: You've completely changed the error message! gaaa I give up.

Comment: i know, i accidently removed the head from my local test file, my bad man

Answer (score 19, accepted):

found the solution: add this to global.asax.cs

```
  protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
    {
        Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
         Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "AllowAll");

    }
```

Comment: My situation: I made a application in ASP.NET MVC 5 and then try to render on a iframe in Sharepoint site, i got the error that says in the tittle of this post, and with your answer everything works fine.

I want to know where did you find this answer?  just to future documentation.

Comment: Is "AllowAll" value a part of any specification? If is not mentioned here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7034